# Angular Object(...) is not a function if subscribe a Service-Api

Tags: angular, api, subscribe

I subscribe to a api request that is called from a service. If I call them from the ngInit I get correct results. If the call comes from button click in the template file, i get an error message:

```
ng:///AppModule/createDestinationDialog.ngfactory.js:116 ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Observable.map (webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operator/map.js:39)
    at HttpClient.request (webpack-internal:///../../../common/esm5/http.js:1553)
    at HttpClient.get (webpack-internal:///../../../common/esm5/http.js:1611)
    at GeocodeService.geocodeAdress (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/services/geocode.service.ts:28)
    at createDestinationDialog.geocode (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/components/trip/createDestinationDialog/createDestinationDialog.component.ts:124)
    at createDestinationDialog.processButtonSearch (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/components/trip/createDestinationDialog/createDestinationDialog.component.ts:121)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/createDestinationDialog.ngfactory.js:122)
    at handleEvent (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13745)
    at callWithDebugContext (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:15254)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14841)
View_createDestinationDialog_0 @ ng:///AppModule/createDestinationDialog.ngfactory.js:116
proxyClass @ webpack-internal:///../../../compiler/esm5/compiler.js:14873
DebugContext_.logError @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:15194
ErrorHandler.handleError @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1716
dispatchEvent @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:10164
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:10785
(anonymous) @ webpack-internal:///../../../platform-browser/esm5/platform-browser.js:2680
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4939
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:420
Zone.runTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:188
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:496
invokeTask @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1517
globalZoneAwareCallback @ webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1543
ng:///AppModule/createDestinationDialog.ngfactory.js:116 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_
```

the error line (This is not my code!!! It's in rxjs/_esm5/operator/map.js):

```
export function map(project, thisArg) {
    return higherOrderMap(project, thisArg)(this); <--Line 37 - it's the operator/map
}
```

my gecode-service

```
export class GeocodeService {
   ....
   geocodeAdress(address: string): Observable {
     return this.http.get<Response>(url, {withCredentials: true});
   } 
 }
```

my component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.geocode('test'); <-- this call works!!!
  }
ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.initializeMap();
    }
processButtonSearch(searchword: string): void { <-- this call comes from a button click in the template file. This call doesn't work 
    this.geocode('test');   
 }

initializeMap(): void {
     var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(this.globalMapDataService.mapStyle);
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("createDestinationMap"), this.globalMapDataService.mapOptions);
     map.mapTypes.set('Map', styledMap);
     map.setMapTypeId('Map');
}
    geocode (searchword: string) {
         this.geocodeService.geocodeAdress('test'); // <--later will be searchword
         .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            error => console.log(error));
   }
```

My HTML:

```
            <div fxLayout="column" class="searchbox">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                  <input fxFlex #searchword class="searchfield" id="autocompleteField"  placeholder="Search Destination">
                  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                  <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Search" (click)="processButtonSearch(searchword.value)">
                    <mat-icon svgIcon="search"></mat-icon>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
<div id="createDestinationMap" style="height: 250px" fxFlex="100" ></div>
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks
Frank

Comment: Please help us help you. Post the html as well and define what you mean by 'doesn't work'. Any errors you are getting? Your `Object(...) is not a function` error probably means that you are trying to call something as a function which isn't a function. This line does look suspicious: `higherOrderMap(project, thisArg)(this)`. Can we see the code for `higherOrderMap`? Is it a wrapper that returns a function, so you are calling it with `this` as an argument?

Comment: I've added my html. The higherorderMap is not my code. It's code of the operator map. I think it's used by the subscribe function. If I load the Page, I get results of my geocoding api. After i type some stuff into the input and click the button, the error 'Object(...) is not a function' comes up.

Comment: Is it the entire stack trace for the `.map` error? Usually somewhere there should be you line of code, which caused the error (by calling `.map`, for example.

Comment: The this.http.get in the service calls the map function. I've added the complete trace. does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I see now, thanks, thinking...

Comment: Is the request being sent in the Network tab? Could you add the `.catch` operator or a second callback to `subscribe` to see what goes wrong exactly?

Comment: I've added the catch to the subscribe function but the request isn't send to the server. I'm  using angular material 2 and at this point I've opened a dialog. Maybe there is some problem with the subscribe function?!

Comment: I created a little example, could you have a look, naybe you'll figure it out? It's simplified but everything works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-su4qld

Comment: Also, I noticed, that you are calling the service with 'test' in your code rather than with `this.geocode(searchword);`

Comment: I know. That was just for testing the API. I cannot see any differences to your example but I'm  using angular material 2 and at this point I've opened a dialog. Maybe there is some problem with the subscribe function in the Dialog?! I think this is the reason for the problem.

Comment: You can use stackblitz to try to recreate your functionality with a dialog. Just google stackblitz with angular material imported.

Comment: I made a small example with the dialog and that worked on stackblitz. But my file structure is a little bit different and I have a Dialog and a Stepper. So it need's a little bit time to build an example. I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks!!

Comment: no problem, I might be here tomorrow as well, so feel free to update your post :)

Comment: I found the issue but i cannot really explain it. It caused because of a map under the input field. Really weird. I added some part of the code and try to rebuild my example in Stackblitz. If i delete the initializeMap function, everything works correctly.

Comment: Ok, let me know when you do

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sec5oj?file=index.html   ...but google isn't working. Any idea?

Comment: Well this isn't helping trace the problem since google is not available. Perhaps you could replace it with some known API, such as https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ ?

Comment: btw, if I comment out everything in the `initializeMap()` everything works fine

Comment: Ok, i've solved it... my variable for the map was 'map' but it was also the import for the operators/map. I changed the name of the map variable. Everything worked. Thank you for your help!               import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map'; = map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("createDestinationMap"), this.globalMapDataService.mapOptions);

Comment: Wow, that was unexpected :) gratz!